# How to test Oracle function with massive data?

Tags: oracle, function

My goal is to test Oracle function with massive data. I use SQLPLUS through the command line (`cmd`) in Windows.

My function below is tested by only 2 row in table DATAB.

How to test my function with a lot of predetermined data? Do I have to repeat INSERT statement with a lot of time?

```
CREATE TABLE DATAB  (  
   AA VARCHAR2(22)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST3
    (P1 IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER AS V_VALUE NUMBER;
BEGIN
    RETURN  P1*100;
END;
/

INSERT INTO DATAB(AA) VALUES (5); --Not a random dataset.
INSERT INTO DATAB(AA) VALUES (6);

SELECT TEST3(AA) FROM DATAB;
```

Answer (score 1):

For your purpose, you can generate test data in several ways, without filling a table with rows.

The following link provides several ways: 
https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Row_Generator_Techniques

Of those, you might want to use the `CONNECT BY` method as this allows you to generate as many test iterations as you want.

```
SELECT TEST3(LEVEL) FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 99999;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming there is no pattern to your test data (for example, that you want to test every number between 1 and 10000).

Your question then becomes "how do I get a lot of data into my Oracle database"?  There are many ways, including:

- Third party tools
- `ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL` tables
- Data loader
- Running a bunch of `INSERT` statements

Here is what I usually do:

1. Get my test data into Microsoft Excel (it's usually there to begin with anyway)
2. Make an Excel formula that computes a string value that is an Oracle `INSERT` statement for the data in that row.  E.g.,

   ="INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (A,B,C) VALUES ('" + $A1 + "', " + $A2 + "," + $A3 + ");"

... if `A` is a `VARCHAR2` and `B` and `C` are `NUMBER` fields, for example.

3. Copy that formula to every row in the spreadsheet that has data
4. Copy the results of the formula and paste them into a file
5. For good measure, but a `BEGIN` and an `END;` at the start and end of the file
6. Run the file

I tend to be old school about these things.  I'll bet there are some nice tools that make this even easier.